# How to find the saved zoom recordings in our computer?

Tags: zoom-sdk

> Want to find the folder system of zoom meeting recordings. Once the meeting is finished, all recordings are auto converted and saved into the system. Right now, I am using macbook pro. Where to find the saved recordings of zoom meetings in macbook?

Comment: Zoom support: [Finding and viewing local recordings](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/206277393), [Getting started with recording](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360059781332-Getting-started-with-recording)

Comment: This seems quite off-topic for Stack Overflow.  The tags are barely applicable.  graphics? 
 forensics?  really?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Particular article is helpful with all different scenario of dealing with recordings.

Comment: @Wyck Rectified tags as per your feedback

Answer (score 0):

By default, local recordings will be placed in following directory:

```
Windows: C:\Users\[Username]\Documents\Zoom
Mac: /Users/[Username]/Documents/Zoom
Linux: home/[Username]/Documents/Zoom
```